# C# and displaying a row randomly for a sight word game

Tags: c#, sql, linq, random

I am trying to get a random generation of a number between the min and max of a table in an access db then match that random number to my table and show the field1column and row that equals that randomized number. I have found a random number generator and some code that should give me the min and max numbers of the table. I want to match my numbers to the row in my table. I am very new to c# programming and am just trying to get a better grasp of programming. Here is my code so far any help would be appreciated. the bold section in the code is where I get an error in my code. Thank you for looking.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CapstoneProgram
{
    public partial class SightWordRandom : Form
    {
        public SightWordRandom()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SightWordRandom_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Double sword;



            var answer = this.sightWordsDB1DataSet.Kindergarten.Aggregate(new { Min = int.MinValue, Max = int.MaxValue },
                                                    (a, b) => new
                                                    {
                                                        Min = Math.Min(a.Min, b.Field<int>("")),
                                                        Max = Math.Max(a.Max, b.Field<int>(""))
                                                    });
            int min = answer.Min;
            int max = answer.Max;

            Random rng = new Random();
            for (int i = min; i < max; i++)

               **sword = (this.sightWordsDB1DataSet.Kindergarten.IDColumn == rng);**

                lblSightWord.Text = Convert.ToString(sword);
        }


    }



    }
```

Comment: Is the lblSightWord within the for loop?

Comment: the variable sword is set as a double, but you are assigning it a boolean. What are you trying to populate the variable sword with? Also what is the actual error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not at all sure that I have understood, here goes a try that may potentially move in the direction of what you intended to do.

I understand the following from your explanation and code:

You need to actually generate a random number to compare to. And I am guessing that you want to generate a number between the determined `min` and `max` values, and select the row in the `Kindergarten` table of which a specific field equals the random number. Apparently this field can be accessed as `Field<int>("")` (this is a little odd, to have a row without a row name, you may want to double check if this is correct, or since you are using a strongly typed dataset, use the member field like you did for `IDColumn`).

For the first row for which this field matches the generated random value, you wish to retrieve the value of another field in that row as `sword`. It is not clear from your current code how this field is named in the `Kindergarten` table. In my proposal below I will refer to it by the string "sword". You may need to change that if in fact the column is named differently.

Also your current code contains a few bugs with the initial values for the `min` and `max` that you aggregate over.

So here goes my proposal:

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Double sword;

    var answer = this.sightWordsDB1DataSet.Kindergarten.Aggregate(
        new { Min = int.MaxValue, Max = int.MinValue },
        (a, b) => new
        {
            Min = Math.Min(a.Min, b.Field<int>("")),
            Max = Math.Max(a.Max, b.Field<int>(""))
        });

    int min = answer.Min;
    int max = answer.Max;
    Random rng = new Random();

    // The value to be matched.
    var selectedMatchingValue = rng.Next(min, max + 1);

    sword = this.sightWordsDB1DataSet.Kindergarten
        .Where(r => r.Field<int>("") == selectedMatchingValue)
        .Select(r => r.Field<double>("sword")) // change to the correct column name.
        .First();

    lblSightWord.Text = Convert.ToString(sword);
}
```